# VBA for excel; editing very large files

Tags: excel, large-files, large-data-volumes, vba

I have a very large set of log files with AIS(shipping) data. Since these log files are about 200Mb per day, I'm trying to size them down for archiving. The files look like this:

```
244630075;under way ;128°'; 0.0kt;52.395290N;4.886883E;342.0°;511°;55s; 170418 000000;serial#1(A)[1]
244670835;under way ;128°'; 0.0kt;52.410140N;4.833700E;283.8°;511°;54s; 170418 000000;serial#1(B)[3]
244750830;under way ;128°'; 0.0kt;52.404563N;4.864063E;  0.0°;511°;55s; 170418 000000;serial#1(B)[1]
244900124;under way ;000°'; 7.1kt;52.426495N;4.780100E;279.4°;281°;56s; 170418 000000;serial#1(B)[2]
244670779;under way ;000°'; 0.0kt;52.420773N;4.801418E;330.9°;325°;58s; 170418 000000;serial#1(A)[1]
244660512;under way ;128°'; 0.0kt;52.402092N;4.781258E;268.3°;511°;54s; 170418 000000;serial#1(B)[1]
236202000;under way ;000°';11.7kt;52.477408N;4.462048E;285.4°;296°;55s; 170418 000000;serial#1(B)[1]
244690403;under way ;128°'; 0.0kt;52.400760N;4.891647E;  0.0°;511°;55s; 170418 000000;serial#1(A)[1]
```

This goes on for about 2 million lines per file. In order to size these files down, I want to remove every line containing " 0.0kt", since that represents information which is not usefull for me. In order to do so, I wrote a VBA script in Excel. I seem to have the script working for the major part. It runs through the file and edits out all lines containing the " 0.0kt". But when the script ends, and should save it exports an empty file.

This is my script:

```
Sub test()
'this will force the script to end when end of file is reached
On Error GoTo ASD

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\x\170418.log", ForReading)

x = 1

Do
Do While i < 1000

        strline = objFile.ReadLine
         If InStr(strline, " 0.0kt") = 28 Then
            strline = "" & vbCrLf

        End If
    i = i + 1

Loop

'doevents and a calculation to call doevents after 1000 lines to prevent freezing of the script
DoEvents
a = a + 1
b = a * 1000
i = i + b
x = i / 1000
i = 0
iLineNumber = x

Loop

ASD:

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\x\170418.log", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strline

objFile.Close

End Sub
```

What am I missing to save and close the file with all the lines containing " 0.0kt" removed, instead of all lines removed?

Thanks

Comment: `strline = objFile.ReadLine` - this *copies* the line into the variable, changing `strline`  after that does nothing to the contents of the file.  Build another string of the lines you *do* want then write that back to the file.

Comment: When you write the file (at the end of the sub) you're writing only the last line you read from the first file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample text, I think any line that contains `; 0.0kt;` can be excluded.

Using something I've already built, I've tweaked it to pick up your your file and use your `DoEvents` every 1000 rows.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ifileno As Integer, ofileno As Integer, rownum As Long
    Dim ifilename As String, ofilename As String, excludestring As String, strLine As String

    ifilename = "C:\Users\v.doynov\Desktop\nd.txt"
    ofilename = "C:\Users\v.doynov\Desktop\nd_output.txt"
    excludestring = "; 0.0kt;"

    ifileno = FreeFile
    Open ifilename For Input As ifileno

    ofileno = FreeFile
    Open ofilename For Output As ofileno

    rownum = 0

    Do Until EOF(ifileno)
        rownum = rownum + 1
        Line Input #ifileno, strLine
        If InStr(strLine, excludestring) = 0 Then Print #ofileno, strLine
        If rownum Mod 1000 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Loop

    Close ifileno
    Close ofileno

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With the useage of your code, I have came up to something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    On Error GoTo ASD
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim x&, i&, strLine$, a&, b&, iLineNumber&
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\v.doynov\Desktop\nd.txt")

    x = 1
    Dim newString As String
    Do
        Do While i < 1000
            strLine = objFile.ReadLine
            If InStr(strLine, " 0.0kt") <> 29 Then 'Sample was 29 on my machine, not 28.
                newString = newString & strLine & vbCrLf
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Loop

ASD:

    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\v.doynov\Desktop\nd.txt", ForWriting)
    objFile.Write newString
    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

---

It checks whether the `If InStr(strLine, " 0.0kt") <> 29 Then` and if it is so, it apends the line to a `newString`. At the end, the `newString` is saved.

Comment: newString = newString & strLine & vbCrLf

This line seems to replace the existing string with the same string (since it uses strLine as input). If i replace strLine with "", I still get an empty file as result.